# Passing parameters between actions ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters from action A to action B.

```
public IActionResult A(string name){ // some code }
public IActionResult B() { return RedirectToAction("A", new {name = "John" }); }
```

This works fine. But what i want to achieve is that these parameters does not show in url, because when i do like the example above, my url looks like `http://myapp.com/users?name=John`. I want url to be clear without ? and following string.

I tried using `TempData[]` and it works locally, but when i publish my application to azure, it not working. 
Tried with `ViewData[]` but found that it goes empty with redirecting.

I tried using javascript to split url, but it has some unnecessary reloadings.

Is there some way to acomplish this, with javascript or .net or something else? 
Thanks

Comment: Best bet without appending parameters to the url is ajax.

Comment: The data has to be part of the request some how. Your choices, in general, are the query string or the request body. However, a redirect will prompt the client to invoke the new location via the GET method, and while technically GET can have a request body according to spec, no major client implementation (including all web browsers) actually supports that. As a result, your only option is the query string in this scenario. You can opt to use something like `TempData`, which is really just a temporary session, but in general, the use of sessions should be avoided.

Comment: HTTP is stateless for a reason. Sessions complicate things dramatically, especially in advanced deployment scenarios such as load balancing/failover.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't like to use the `...?name=John&p2=val2` in your url, while your action is accepting a `GET` method...

Anyway, you can write this if you are in a same controller (which is not a good practice)

```
     public IActionResult A(string name){}
     public IActionResult B(){return A("world");}
```

Or

use TempData: here, your problem would be **`TempData[]` not working on azure**. So you should set up the cookie consent like this

```
   services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
```

Bear in mind that you have to clear your browser navigation data including cookies and also accept the app to store/collect cookie.